# How can extract word between special character and other words

Tags: bash

I am trying to find a way, how to extract a word between special character and other words.

Example of the text:

```
description "CST 500M TEST/VPNGW/11040 X {} // test"

description "test2-VPNGW-110642 -VPNGW"
```

I am trying to achieve result like,only the word including `VPNGW`:

```
TEST/VPNGW/11040

test2-VPNGW-110642
```

I tried with grep and AWK, but looks like my knowledge is not so far enough.
The way to print with `awk '{$1=""; $2=""; ...` is not working due to the whole word is not always on the same position.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks, but in that case resul looks like:

./test2  | grep -o '".*VPNGW' 
"CST 500M TEST/VPNGW
"test2-VPNGW-110642 -VPNGW

So we are missing the numbers on the first one and on the second row we have additional -VPNGW which we don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With grep you can output only the part of the string that matches the regex:

```
grep -o '[^ "]\+VPNGW[^ "]\+' file.name
```

Comment: Thanks, but in that case resul looks like: ./test2 | grep -o '".*VPNGW' "CST 500M TEST/VPNGW "test2-VPNGW-110642 -VPNGW So we are missing the numbers on the first one and on the second row we have additional -VPNGW which we don't

Comment: @RadostinTodorov I've updated the regex to match your examples. This should be good if `VPNGW` is a middle part of the word. There can be some corner cases when VPNGW is at the beginning or the end of the word and not in the end of the text in double quotes.

Comment: @RadostinTodorov please don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
grep -Eoi 'test.*[0-9]'
```

Of course this would be greedy and if there is another number after the ones in the required string it will grab up to there.  Normally I would suggest an inverted test to stop at the thing you don't want:

```
grep -Eoi 'test[^ ]+'
```

The problem with this is like in your first example, there is more than one occurrence of the string 'test' and so the output for the first example is:

```
TEST/VPNGW/11040
test"
```

Of course knowing what your real data looks like you can make your own decision on what might best suit

Uou could go with the perl regex machine in grep and use a look-ahead:

```
grep -Eoi 'test[^ ]+(?= )'
```

Again though, if you have the string 'test' somewhere else on the line followed by a single space, this will still not work as desired.

Lastly, awk can do the job but you would need to cycle through each item or set RS to white space:

Option 1:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(tolower($i) ~ /test.*[0-9]/)print $i}'
```

Option 2:

```
awk 'tolower($i) ~ /test.*[0-9]/' RS="[[:space:]]+"
```

Comment: Yea, but looks like is missing the other one. Basically all of the word starts with " and finish with 0-9, but in some cases we have the way like
description "CST 500M TEST/VPNGW/11040 X {} // test"
and then we cannot extract the right one. Always the word VPNGW is between // or --.

./test2  | awk 'tolower($i) ~ /".*[0-9]/' RS="[[:space:]]+"

"test2-VPNGW-110642

Comment: So put the double quotes into the character class.  At the end of the day I can come up with just as many ways that don't work.  The idea is that the answers here should lead you to a solution, they do not always have to be the exact solution, which would not be possible as I do not know anything about the real data.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/test2/{sub(/"/,"")}$0{print $4}/test2/{print $2}' file

TEST/VPNGW/11040

test2-VPNGW-110642
```